# Buildozer Android packaging error - sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: <exception str() failed>

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I try to build an APK of a Kivy app. I am building on a fresh install of VirtualBox, a virtual machine for Ubuntu.
The app I am trying to build is (as a starter) a standard app of the Kivy Tutorials, so it is unlikely that this is the cause of the error.

I have found out what the problem was (even though I do not understand why this was a problem), see below. I wanted to share this via a Q&A.

Logs:

```
kivy@kivyvm:/media/sf_HelloWorld$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.10 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5" "jinja2" "six"'
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=tutorial --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Found multiple valid dependency orders:
[INFO]:        ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:        ['hostpython3crystax', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python3crystax', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:        ['hostpython2', 'pygame_bootstrap_components', 'python2', 'sdl', 'six', 'pygame', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    Using the first of these: ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2_gradle
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2_gradle bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name tutorial and recipes (kivy)
[INFO]:    Dist will also contain modules () installed from pip
[INFO]:    -> running cp -r /media/sf_HelloWorld/.bu...(and 194 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 54 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    hostpython2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 53 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_image download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 53 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 51 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 48 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading python2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 50 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    python2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/....(and 46 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org...(and 26 more)
[INFO]:    sdl2 download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/....(and 45 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.or...(and 40 more)
     [INFO]:    six download already cached, skipping                          
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/...(and 50 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 28 more)
[INFO]:    pyjnius download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /media/sf_HelloWorld/....(and 46 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kiv...(and 25 more)
[INFO]:    kivy download already cached, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://python.org/ftp...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop
[INFO]:    hostpython2 is already unpacked, skipping
[INFO]:    <- directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.or...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2_gradle-python2/jni
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 559, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 520, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 422, in unpack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1245, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 633, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 651, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: <exception str() failed>
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=tutorial --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_HelloWorld/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Buildozer configuration file `/media/sf_HelloWorld/buildozer.spec`: I only changed the name and the log level.

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Tutorial

# (str) Package name
package.name = tutorial

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Python code of `/media/sf_HelloWorld/main.py` (copy from Kivy tutorial):

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text="Hello!",
                  font_size=150)

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that it did not work because I used the shared folder between VirtualBox and the Windows host, **/media**.

When I copied the files to another folder, the build succeeded!

Comment: Thanks, happened the same thing to me and solved my problem too.